# Will moving a sound source in ATMOS just "blend" the sound, or will it create a Doppler-effect?

Tags: audio, davinci-resolve

Intending to make a test video using Dolby ATMOS in Resolve 18.1 I wonder:
When I have a sound recorded at some fixed spot, and I want that sound to move in space via the ATMOS controls, will Resolve just blend the sound across the speaker channels, or will it add a Doppler-effect?

Also I wonder: If Resolve is working with a "unit cube", can a Doppler-effect be created correctly at all (meaning: If you don't know the real speed, you cannot compute the effect, right?)?